# "Open with" option in Windows 10 context menu grayed out for unknown reason

Tags: windows-10, operating-systems, context-menu

So, title is pretty self explanatory, but I suddenly noticed that my "Open with" option in the Windows 10 context menu is grayed out.

[image: Screenshot.]

Does anybody know what might be the reason and the antidote?

Comment: Do you have administrative privileges on this computer?

Comment: What file extension?

Comment: @Ramhound Since it defaults to `Play` and also shows other VLC commands, I'm guessing it's a video file. However, the file at the likely position of the mouse pointer appears to be an `exe`...

Comment: @Ramhound Happens with all file extensions.

Comment: @LPChip Yes, I do.

Comment: @user197120 time to Refresh/Reset your installation